# Why is the for loop assigning 0 in the array?

Tags: java, arrays

Need to separate odds and evens from an array and put them into their own array. The for loops keep adding a 0 to the evenA and oddA arrays if the spot is not filled in. Cannot figure this one out.

```
    //Figure out length of odd and even array

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if ((arr[i] % 2) == 0) {
            evens += 1;
        }
        else {
            odds += 1;
        }
    }

    //Create new arrays for both even and odds

    int[] evenA = new int[evens];
    int[] oddA = new int[odds];
    
    //Add the even numbers and odd numbers to the arrays.

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if ((arr[i] % 2) == 0) {
            evenA[j] = arr[i];
        }
        else {
                oddA[j] = arr[i];
        }
    }
```

Example Output:

```
    Array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
    
    evenA[] = {0, 2, 0, 4}
    oddA[] = {1, 0, 3, 0, 5}
```

Then, it stops running. I need to get rid of the zeroes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Where do you declare `j`; where do you increment `j`?  Please copy/paste the actual code, don't retype it into the question.
This site is not a discussion forum or programming tutorial site.
Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read [Ask] to learn how to use this site effectively.

Comment: I'm assuming 0 is in your source array.  if so, it's because 0 divided by 2 is 0, hence the modulo is 0 and even.

Comment: What do you expect the output to look like?  {2,4,6,8} and {1,3,5,7,9}?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not putting zeros into the array. The array was filled with zeros and both array indexes are being incremented. So, the values are being put into every other index location. To fix, track the indexes of even and odd arrays separately:

```
int oddPtr = 0;
int evenPtr = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if ((arr[i] % 2) == 0) {
        evenA[evenPtr++] = arr[i];
    }
    else {
        oddA[oddPtr++] = arr[i];
    }
}
```

Lastly, the size of both even and odd arrays should be approximately half of the original array.

**UPDATE**:

I can't believe some of the comments below the OP's question. So I am explaining more details about the zeros in the arrays.  The line:

```
int[] evenA = new int[evens];
```

creates an array of length `evens` (lets assume 4), where every element in the array is initialized with the default value of `int` data type; which is zero. Therefore, `evenA` looked like:

```
evenA => {0,0,0,0};
```

Because the index counter (pointer) was incremented every iteration AND it was shared between the two arrays, the insertion of odd and even values was interlaced with respect to each other:

```
{0,2,0,4,0}
{1,0,3,0,5}
```

So, every odd index location contained even numbers and even index locations contained odd numbers as illustrated above. That is why the solution I provided contains two index pointers so that each is used and incremented only when the conditions for determining odd or even is matched.

Comment: Why their sized should be 'approximately half' ? one could even be an empty one if there are no even numbers or odds ones.

Comment: @LiavC You have to assume there is an even distribution of odd and even numbers. If that is not enough, then you need to resize the array. Alternatively, use an `ArrayList` instead of an array. If you make them larger, then the tail end of the array will be padded with zeros. In that case, you will need to create another function to "remove" indexes containing zeros at the end.

Comment: @LiavC calculating the size of the needed arrays is OK because it will always create an array of the correct size. However, the inefficiency comes in the fact that you iterate through the source array twice and figure out odd and even numbers twice as well. It might be better off to "predict" the size of the odd and even arrays and then handle a method for resizing the array if the destination array is full. Also, you will need to clean the tail end if not all positions were taken. There is no correct answer. It is all about tradeoffs.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, I am new to Java and I'm coming from a limited knowledge of Python. I didn't know that zeroes filled an empty array. I used the pointers you used in the example to keep track of the indexes, I appreciate it!

Comment: @OMeihls in Java, an array of primitives are filled with the default value of that primitive. For booleans, that value is `false`, for numeric values is zero, for `char` that's the unicode null character, and for objects (including String), the default value is `null`. Always remember that rule.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using the same counter for both arrays your array are getting filled inconsistently. You are using the same j variable for both array assignment. For example, if u have the following array

```
int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

And j = 0; intially. Your loop would look something like this:

First iteration:

oddA = {0, 0}; evenA = {0, 0};

j = 0; i = 0;

As the first element in the array is  odd:
j = 1; oddA = {1, 0}; evenA = {0, 0};

The next iteration:

oddA = {1, 0}; evenA = {0, 0};

j = 1; i = 1;

As the second element in the array is  even:

j = 1; oddA = {1, 0};

evenA[j] = 2 => evenA = {0, 2};

Instead you should use two different counters for your evenA and oddA arrays.

```
int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    int evens = 0, odds = 0;
    for (int num : arr) {
        if (num % 2 == 0) evens++;
        else odds++;
    }

    int[] evenA = new int[evens];
    int[] oddA = new int[odds];

    // Creating separate array counters
    int evenArrayCounter = 0;
    int oddArrayCounter = 0;

    for (int num : arr) {
        if (num % 2 == 0) evenA[evenArrayCounter++] = num;
        else oddA[oddArrayCounter++] = num;
    }
```

Comment: "code-only" answers are frowned upon in the Stack Overflow community. The answer to the question "**_Why is the for loop assigning 0 in the array?_**" is not answered explicitly anywhere on your answer. I don't downvote (normally) these answers, but I can assure you others will.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am new to this community. I will change my answer